# How do I get information on my html page from an api call

Tags: python, html

I am trying to display information on my html page from a api call to coinmarketcap.com. I have the user place a slug name of a cryptocurrency in the previous page, send a form with that information, then use it in my view to print to console. How would I use this information on my html page to display it.

main.py

```
from requests import Request, Session
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects
import json



    def cryptoLookup(coin):
        url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/info'
        parameters = {
            'slug': coin
        }
        headers = {
            'Accepts': 'application/json',
            'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': '',
        }
    
        session = Session()
        session.headers.update(headers)
    
        try:
            response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
            data = json.loads(response.text)
            print(data)
        except (ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects) as e:
            print(e)
```

home.html

```
<h1>home</h1>
<form action="{% url 'coin' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Which coin would you like to lookup?</h1>
    <input id='coin-lookup' name='coin-lookup' type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
enter code here
```

views.py

```
def coin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        coin = request.POST.get('coin-lookup')
        cryptoLookup(coin)
    return render(request, 'app/coin.html')
```